# Matcher.group() not giving correct output

Tags: java, regex

I have a simple program.

```
public class RaviTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("The test ID is (.*?)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("The test ID is 152454");
        System.out.println(matcher.find());
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

The output I expect from this program is "152454", however it is printing a whitespace "".

If I try to print matcher.group(0), it prints "The test ID is ".

Edit:

If I use matcher.matches() instead of matcher.find(), it prints correctly.

Please help me understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: `.*?` is 'optionally, zero or more any characters', isn't it? Try `.+`.

Comment: In case you don't know it yet, regex101.com is a nice place to test regex. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/6kLKR2/1/) is one with your example.

Comment: Thanks @EganWolf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` matches between 0 and unlimited times, and `?` makes it lazy, meaning that it will try to match as few times as possible, so in this case, `.*?` will always match an empty string.

You can try removing the `?` to make it greedy, or just replace `*?` with `+` to make it match between 1 and unlimited times.

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper, it worked. But I would like to know the difference between .* and .+ (but I understood greedy vs lazy)

Comment: `.*` matches zero or more times, `.+` matches one or more times (i.e. at least one time)

Comment: @Ravi `.*` will match zero or more times. It will match even if there is an empty string. And there must be at least one character that matches `.` for `.+` to match.

Comment: Thanks Erich and Sweeper. I got what I am looking for